# Webdriverio & Selenium throw NoSessionIdError & RuntimeError

Tags: node.js, selenium, amazon-ecs, webdriver-io

I'm running on Amazon ECS a cluster of Selenium Standalone Server w/ Firefox attached to another container for my API.

I'm querying my API to get a response and a screenshot of a long running webpage. 90% of the time, I'm getting a NoSessionIdError or a RuntimeError

`{ Error: A session id is required for this command but wasn't found in the response payload
at execute(<Function>) - selectorExecute.js:58:65
at execute("return !!document.evaluate;") - ensureClientSideSelectorSupport.js:23:17
type: 'NoSessionIdError',
message: 'A session id is required for this command but wasn\'t found in the response payload' }`

`{ status: -1,
type: 'ESOCKETTIMEDOUT',
message: 'Couldn\'t connect to selenium server',
orgStatusMessage: 'ESOCKETTIMEDOUT' } }`

Here is my code :

```
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
var options = {
    desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'firefox'

    },
    host: 'selenium'
};


var WebRefresh = function () {
    this.client = webdriverio.remote(options);
    this.statusMessage = "";
    this.errorMessage = "";
};

WebRefresh.prototype.refreshURL = function (url, cb) {
    var self = this;
    self.client
        .init()
        .url(url)
        .pause(10000)
        .element('iframe').then(function(res)
        {
            console.log("FRAME 1");
            return self.client.frame(res.value).waitUntil(
                function () {
                    return self.client.getHTML('.statusMessageHolder=Success.');
                }, 300000, "TIMED OUT", 1000);
        }).catch(function (err) {
        self.errorMessage += "WaitUntil-" + err.type + "| ";
        console.error(err);
    })
        .getHTML('.statusMessageHolder', false).then(function (text) {
        self.statusMessage = text;
    }).catch(function (err) {
        self.errorMessage += "GetStatus-" + err.type + "| ";

    })
        .getHTML('.error-title', false).then(function (text) {
            self.errorMessage = text;
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.error(err);
        self.errorMessage += "GetError-" + err.type + "| ";

    }).screenshot().then(
        function (data) {
            cb(self.statusMessage, self.errorMessage, data.value);

        }).catch(function (err) {
        console.error(err);
        self.errorMessage += "GetScreenshot-" + err.type + "| ";
        cb(self.statusMessage, self.errorMessage, undefined);

    })
        .end();

    self.client.on('error', function(err) {
        console.error(err);
    });

};



module.exports = WebRefresh;
```

I'm sure there is something wrong with that, I'm not used to promise. Could you help me ?

**EDIT**

I have 1 Selenium instance linked to 1 API instance, 10 instances in parallel behind an ELB. I have 500 request I need to send, with 10 request per batch. I'm waiting to get a response before sending another request.

I switched to Chrome, results are a bit better but still not what I expect. First requests have better results than other ones.

I added `.manage().deleteAllCookies().close().end();` at the end but it's not making a huge difference.

Comment: Does that mean that you leave browser open for a long time and then come back again to same browser and do some action?

Comment: The browser should be pinged every second when I'm looking for my Success Message.

Comment: @loicbertron afaik , after `.end` is called , it will not execute any commands because there is no session try moving `self.client.on('error', function(err) {
        console.error(err);
    });` inside